# PHP + APACHE + LDAP + SSO: How to get the current user MemberOf and DisplayName attribute?

Tags: php, windows, apache, ldap, single-sign-on

I have a web application that currently asks for the user to fill the username and password in a Login page. My idea is to use **SSO** to avoid the manual input of these information.

After some hours modifying the **httpd.conf** file, I was able to make my web application get the current Window's username with the `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];` command.

To compare some access inside the application, unfortunately, I also need the groups that he is currently in. In this case, it would be the Active Directory `memberOf` attribute

Considering that the manual login will not be done, how can may I get the `memberOf` attribute? Should I query the user again to get this information or is there a better approach?

By the way, I am currently using:

- Apache Version 2.4.33 x64
- PHP Version 7.2.4 x64
- WAMPServer Version 3.1.3 x64
- Windows Server 2008 x64

Just for comparison, the current code that I use to retrieve the groups and the `DisplayName` attribute. It works well, but, requires a manual user and password input:

```
public function Login($user, $pass, $remember = false){
    require_once("ad.class.php");   
    $ldap = new Ldap();
    $ret = $ldap->Bind($user, $pass);

    $redirect = RedirectURL($this->redirect);

    if ($ret){

        $filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=$user))";
        $attributes  = array("displayname","samaccountname","memberof");

        $info = $ldap->GetEntries($filter, $attributes);

        $aGrp = array();
        if (count($info) > 0){
            foreach ($info[0]['memberof'] as $member) {
                $aMember = explode(",", $member);
                $grp = str_replace("CN=\\", "", $aMember[0]);
                $grp = str_replace("CN=", "", $grp);
                $aGrp[] = $grp;
            }
        }

        if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

        $_SESSION['session_login'] = array();
        $_SESSION['session_login']['user']  = $info[0]["samaccountname"][0];
        $_SESSION['session_login']['name']  = $info[0]["displayname"][0];
        $_SESSION['session_login']['grp']   = $aGrp;
        $_SESSION['lang']                   = getDefaultLanguage();

        if ($remember){
            $expire = (time() + (15 * 24 * 3600)); //15 dias

            setcookie('cookie_login', $_SESSION['session_login'], $expire);
        }

        accessLog(getCurrentUser(), 'Authorized - LDAP');               
        header("Location: index.php?redirect=" . $redirect);

        return true;
    }else{
        $ret['redirect'] = $redirect;
        $this->errors = $ret; //$this->redirect

        accessLog(getCurrentUser(), 'Access Denied - LDAP');
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSO doesn't free you (your users) from an authentication process, eventually they WILL have to this, however it may look like.

There are several libraries available for all kinds of SSO, but if you want to the "real" SSO in a Web environment, SAML2 with HTTP POST binding, you're hardly coming around the simplesaml library: https://simplesamlphp.org/

I would recommend this library over any attempt, to implement an hack... with simplesaml you get an full-featured industry-standard SSO that can connect easily with other Identity Providers, like ADFS on Windows.

hth